# count, sorting numbers and filter in tibble

Tags: r

Given below data,I try to find the most frequently used bike’s data records.I need to find the bikeid that has the highest number of records. Then using the highest bikeid, filter my data for only that bikeid and display only those records.

```
 library(lubridate)
 library(tidyverse)
 nycbikes18 <- read_csv("data/2018-citibike-tripdata.csv",
 locale = locale(tz = "America/New_York"))
 nycbikes18
 #> # A tibble: 333,687 x 15
 #>    tripduration starttime           stoptime           
 #>           <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 #>  1          932 2018-01-01 02:06:17 2018-01-01 02:21:50
 #>  2          550 2018-01-01 12:06:18 2018-01-01 12:15:28
 #>  3          510 2018-01-01 12:06:56 2018-01-01 12:15:27
 #>  4          354 2018-01-01 14:53:10 2018-01-01 14:59:05
 #>  5          250 2018-01-01 17:34:30 2018-01-01 17:38:40
 #>  6          613 2018-01-01 22:05:05 2018-01-01 22:15:19
 #>  7          290 2018-01-02 12:13:51 2018-01-02 12:18:42
 #>  8          381 2018-01-02 12:50:03 2018-01-02 12:56:24
 #>  9          318 2018-01-02 13:55:58 2018-01-02 14:01:16
 #> 10         1852 2018-01-02 16:55:29 2018-01-02 17:26:22
 #> # … with 333,677 more rows, and 12 more variables:
 #> #   start_station_id <dbl>, start_station_name <chr>,
 #> #   start_station_latitude <dbl>, start_station_longitude <dbl>,
 #> #   end_station_id <dbl>, end_station_name <chr>,
 #> #   end_station_latitude <dbl>, end_station_longitude <dbl>,
 #> #   bikeid <dbl>, usertype <chr>, birth_year <dbl>, gender <dbl>
```

my code and output

```
top_bike_trips <- nycbikes18%>%group_by(bikeid) %>% filter( tripduration==max(tripduration))
top_bike_trips

# A tibble: 900 x 15
# Groups:   bikeid [900]
tripduration starttime           stoptime           
      <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1         2111 2018-01-11 15:33:24 2018-01-11 16:08:36
2        21262 2018-01-12 13:00:26 2018-01-12 18:54:48
3         1804 2018-01-12 17:10:56 2018-01-12 17:41:01
4         2717 2018-01-30 18:03:31 2018-01-30 18:48:49
5         1892 2018-01-19 18:40:06 2018-01-19 19:11:39
6          563 2018-01-31 09:20:28 2018-01-31 09:29:51
7        50545 2018-01-02 17:58:07 2018-01-03 08:00:32
8          475 2018-01-03 18:03:39 2018-01-03 18:11:34
9        30997 2018-01-19 08:43:44 2018-01-19 17:20:22
10        80854 2018-01-19 18:50:43 2018-01-20 17:18:18
# ... with 890 more rows, and 12 more variables:
```

expected output

```
top_bike_trips
#> # A tibble: 825 x 15
#>    tripduration starttime           stoptime           
#>           <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#>  1          520 2018-01-03 13:06:21 2018-01-03 13:15:01
#>  2          232 2018-01-03 17:01:21 2018-01-03 17:05:14
#>  3          315 2018-01-14 15:08:14 2018-01-14 15:13:30
#>  4          266 2018-01-23 14:57:30 2018-01-23 15:01:57
#>  5          162 2018-01-24 17:01:10 2018-01-24 17:03:53
#>  6          150 2018-01-25 18:26:58 2018-01-25 18:29:29
#>  7          272 2018-01-03 08:49:11 2018-01-03 08:53:43
#>  8          315 2018-01-20 14:06:28 2018-01-20 14:11:44
#>  9          322 2018-01-02 15:43:42 2018-01-02 15:49:04
#> 10          251 2018-01-10 17:48:03 2018-01-10 17:52:14
#> # … with 815 more rows, and 12 more variables:
#> #   start_station_id <dbl>, start_station_name <chr>,
#> #   start_station_latitude <dbl>, start_station_longitude <dbl>,
#> #   end_station_id <dbl>, end_station_name <chr>,
#> #   end_station_latitude <dbl>, end_station_longitude <dbl>,
#> #   bikeid <dbl>, usertype <chr>, birth_year <dbl>, gender <dbl>
```

I'm not sure how to get the expected output 825,maybe use count() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == names(which.max(table(cyl))))
#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
# Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
# Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
# Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
# Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
# Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
# Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
# Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
# Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

From this, it might be enough to try

```r
nycbikes18 %>%
  filter(bikeid == names(which.max(table(bikeid))))
```

---

Alternatively, since we have to guess about the data. If instead you mean the `bikeid` with the highest `tripdurations` number, then perhaps

```r
nycbikes18 %>%
  filter(bikeid == bikeid[which.max(tripdurations)])
```

Comment: Hi，Can I ask if my bikeid are all different, and I need to find the bikeid that has the highest number of records, how do I modify the code? Thanks！

Comment: If your `bikeid` are all different, the last code-block will return a frame with just that `bikeid` based on the highest value of `tripdurations`. If you need the `bikeid` with the most occurrences in the original frame, then the second code-block will return that frame. Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Calculate the modal bike id: modal_bike_id => character scalar
modal_bike_id <- tail(names(sort(table(bikeid))), 1)

# Subset data set to only contain modal bike id's records: data.frame => stdout(console)
nycbikes18[
  with(
    nycbikes18,
    bikeid == modal_bike_id
  ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `mtcars` data as example :

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  count(cyl) %>%
  slice_max(n = 1, n) %>%
  select(cyl) %>%
  left_join(mtcars, by = 'cyl')

#   cyl  mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1    8 18.7 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#2    8 14.3 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#3    8 16.4 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#4    8 17.3 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#5    8 15.2 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#6    8 10.4 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#7    8 10.4 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#8    8 14.7 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#9    8 15.5 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#10   8 15.2 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#11   8 13.3 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#12   8 19.2 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#13   8 15.8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#14   8 15.0 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```